# Position Not Moving Despite of Key Listener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I made the Card Layout Working completely fine but what happened now is I added a keylistener to the object character which is a JLabel so whenever the person presses up the character should move up but it does absolutely nothing!

I also tried replacing it with a button which moves it when clicked and it worked completely fine. Also I tried changing the event meaning I changed that if they press up then the image of the town map would change but still no effect so it seems there is something wrong with my KeyListener

`import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;`
`import java.awt.event.ActionListener;`
`import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;`
`import java.awt.event.KeyListener;`
`import java.awt.*;`
`import javax.swing.*;`

`@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "serial" })`
`public class FinalBlowzXC extends JFrame implements KeyListener{`

```
public static JPanel game=new JPanel();
public static JPanel mainmenu=new JPanel(null);
public static JPanel loginpanel=new JPanel(null);
public static JPanel tutorial=new JPanel(null);
public static JPanel registration=new JPanel(null);
public static JPanel town_map=new JPanel(null);
public JTextField username= new JTextField("Username");
public JTextField password=new JTextField("Password");
public  JLabel bglogin=new JLabel();
public JLabel character=new JLabel();
public  JButton log_in=new JButton();
public  JButton register=new JButton();
CardLayout page= new CardLayout();
public String level="";
public int charx=350;
public int chary=435;

public static void main(String []args)
{
    new FinalBlowzXC().setVisible(true);
}

public FinalBlowzXC()
{
    super("Final Blowz Xchanged");
    setSize(640,510);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    game.setLayout(page);
    game.add(mainmenu, "1");
    game.add(loginpanel, "2");
    game.add(tutorial, "3");
    game.add(registration, "4");
    game.add(town_map, "5");
    add(game);
    opening();
}

    public void opening()
    {
        page.show(game, "1");
        JLabel bgmainmenu;
        JButton start;
        JButton exit;
        bgmainmenu = new JLabel();
        start = new JButton();
        exit = new JButton();

        bgmainmenu.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/FF-XV.jpg")));
        bgmainmenu.setBounds(0,0,640,480);
        mainmenu.add(bgmainmenu);
        mainmenu.add(start);
        start.setBounds(280, 360, 70, 20);
        start.setBorder(null);
        start.setBorderPainted(false);
        start.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        start.setOpaque(false);
        start.addActionListener(new Start());
        exit.setBounds(280, 385, 70, 20);
        mainmenu.add(exit);
        exit.setBorder(null);
        exit.setBorderPainted(false);
        exit.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        exit.setOpaque(false);
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }


    class Start implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            login();

    }

}

    public void login()
    {
        page.show(game, "2");

        bglogin.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/FF-XV Login.jpg")));
        bglogin.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);


        username.setBounds(300, 285, 85, 15);
        username.setBorder(null);
        username.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        username.setOpaque(false);

        password.setBounds(300, 310, 85, 20);
        password.setBorder(null);
        password.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        password.setOpaque(false);

        log_in.setBounds(280, 335, 50, 45);
        log_in.setBorder(null);
        log_in.setBorderPainted(false);
        log_in.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        log_in.setOpaque(false);
        log_in.addActionListener(new Log_in());

        register.setBounds(335, 335, 55, 45);
        register.setBorder(null);
        register.setBorderPainted(false);
        register.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        register.setOpaque(false);
        register.addActionListener(new Register());

        loginpanel.add(username);
        loginpanel.add(password);
        loginpanel.add(bglogin);
        loginpanel.add(log_in);
        loginpanel.add(register);
    }

    class Log_in implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            Tutorial();

        }

    }

    class Register implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            page.show(game, "4");
        }
    }

    public void Tutorial()
    {
        page.show(game, "3");
        JLabel bgtutorial=new JLabel();
        JLabel animeforward=new JLabel();
        JLabel animeright=new JLabel();
        JLabel animeleft=new JLabel();
        JButton next=new JButton();
        JLabel animebackward=new JLabel();
        bgtutorial.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/FF-XV Tutorial.jpg")));
        bgtutorial.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        animeforward.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialfront.gif")));
        animeforward.setBounds(115, 230, 30, 30);
        animeright.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialright.gif")));
        animeright.setBounds(190, 315, 30, 30);
        animeleft.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialleft.gif")));
        animeleft.setBounds(45, 315, 30, 30);
        animebackward.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialback.gif")));
        animebackward.setBounds(115, 405, 30, 30);
        next.setBounds(530, 430, 100, 30);
        next.setBorder(null);
        next.setBorderPainted(false);
        next.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        next.setOpaque(false);
        next.addActionListener(new Next());
        tutorial.add(next);
        tutorial.add(animeright);
        tutorial.add(animeleft);
        tutorial.add(animebackward);
        tutorial.add(animeforward);
        tutorial.add(bgtutorial);

    }

    class Next implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            town();
        }
    }

    public void town()
    {
        page.show(game, "5");
        JLabel map=new JLabel();
        map.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/FF-XV Town.jpg")));
        map.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 480);
        character.setIcon(new  ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("standfront.png")));
        character.setBounds(charx, chary, 30, 35);
        town_map.add(character);
        town_map.add(map);

    }   


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            character.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialfront.gif")));
            character.setLocation(character.getX(), character.getY()+5);
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            character.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialright.gif")));
            character.setLocation(character.getX()+5, character.getY());
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            character.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialleft.gif")));
            character.setLocation(character.getX()-5, character.getY()+5);
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            character.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walkanimofficialback.gif")));
            character.setLocation(character.getX(), character.getY()-5);
        }

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {


    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


    }
```

}

Comment: *"I want the card layout to work but for some reason it is not working"* The reason is very specific, and programmers need to deal with these types of problems regularly. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Please do not deface your question. Doing this is totally against site rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code in your programme.

```
public static JPanel mainmenu = new JPanel();
public static JPanel loginpanel = new JPanel();
```

or initialize `mainmenu` & `loginpanel` before adding them into the `game` panel.

Comment: I did but due to my reputation not over 15 I am unable to do so

Answer (score 0):

when you call `game.add(loginPanel, "2")` `loginPanel` is `null`